# Change Currency in aspx vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, localization

I have been given a website in aspx and I had to make some changes. Unfortunately I am not a programmer, but I have managed to do most of the changes by looking at the code and using common sense. 
But they only thing I am not able to do is change the currency from $( us dollars) to £(GBP) 
basically I have a form with a dropdown list( see image)  [drop down menu with $](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCORX.jpg)
and the code is this

```
InsertFirstListItem(DropDownCoverAmount, "How much cover would you like?", "")
DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem("Less than £50,000", "upto50"))
For intLoop As Integer = 50000 To 700000 Step 10000
DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem(intLoop.ToString("C0"), intLoop.ToString))
Next
DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem("More than £700,000", "above700"))
```

It's going up by 10.000 from 50.000 to 700.000
But it does it in dollars. How and where would I change it to GPB £

Any Help will be highly appreciated

**Update** (2018-06-18 12:39:19Z):

Following the comments, the code is now

```
InsertFirstListItem(DropDownCoverAmount, "How much cover would you like?", "")
DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem("Less than £50,000", "upto50"))
Dim ci = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
For intLoop As Integer = 50000 To 700000 Step 10000
    DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem(intLoop.ToString("C0", ci), intLoop.ToString))
```

but still getting errors.

Comment: The ["C"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) format string formats as currency by adding the currency symbol of the current culture. You want the "en-GB" culture. Or just format as plain number and add the "£" yourself

Comment: thank you, I just looked on how i could do this and found this suggestion... would it be correct? DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem(intLoop.ToString("C0" new CultureInfo("en-GB")), intLoop.ToString))

Comment: Nope I just Tried I got all sort of errors ... Could you suggest where to add the "en-GB" culture in the code please ?

Comment: Put the line `Dim ci = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")` just before the `For intLoop...` line, and use `intLoop.ToString("C0", ci)` to get the amount with the £ symbol.

Comment: Oh Thank you  very much for your help, I have done this: InsertFirstListItem(DropDownCoverAmount, "How much cover would you like?", "")
        DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem("Less than £50,000", "upto50"))
 Dim ci = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB")
        For intLoop As Integer = 50000 To 700000 Step 10000
            DropDownCoverAmount.Items.Add(New ListItem(intLoop.ToString("C0", ci), intLoop.ToString)) but still getting errors :(

Comment: Please add the the extra code to your question, as its hard to read in a comment.

Comment: @Andrea I edited the code into your question for you, but you're going to have to tell us exactly what the errors are.